# Entering USA on pending I-130 petition

Tags: visas, usa

I am a 57 years old married person having 4 children. I have been traveling to the UK and Europe a lot for business purposes. My brother is in the USA & had applied for I-130 in 2017.

I want to exhibit in Las Vegas and grow my business there. In the case of I-130 case takes about 14 years. I heard when you apply for I130 you can't justify on a b1/b2 visa that you will come back to your country and your visa is rejected. Is there any way I can convince the visa officer this is not the case?

Comment: I know plenty of people who were traveling to the US while their I130 based on family was pending. Where did you here that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being the beneficiary of a pending or approved I-130 does not mean you cannot convince the officer that you don't intend to immigrate on this stay. As with any other nonimmigrant entry, it will be up to the officer to determine whether you have overcome the presumption of immigrant intent.